# WinRt: Dispose a page

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, idisposable

I'm wondering how to dispose a Page correctly in WinRT.

In my page_loaded event I hook several events like:

```
_navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
_navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
_button.Click += button_click;
```

As I don't have an instance from my page I can not dispose it.
Am I responsible to unhook such events?

Is it right that if the destructor is called everything is disposed and the GC takes care of all references?

Many thanks
Dani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your page doesn't hold references to large resources - it might be fine to just let it be garbage collected. Otherwise you can consider releasing those on the `Unloaded` event or 
`OnNavigatedFrom()` override. The page itself doesn't implement `IDisposable`, so you can't dispose it and it's likely not what you'd want since a control like `Page` is not a heavy resource.

Overall - garbage collection takes care of all objects that lose a path to GC root. You just need to make sure you don't cause a leak by leaving such a connection hanging (I'd say most typically by not removing static event handlers). To release larger resources you should implement the `IDisposable` interface correctly (look up "IDisposable pattern").

Comment: Thanks, so man can say that if the destructor has been called there is no leak?

Comment: Actually - typically you don't call or implement a destructor at all. Otherwise - it's not so simple. Many things can leak and the fact that your page was GC'd doesn't mean all the resources it used are since some of these resources might not be managed (by GC). Some of them might be large and should be disposed before you go to another page to leave room for new resources.

Comment: ok, understood. In my current application I have the problem that the application is slowing down after a few calls/pages. Is there a possibility to find leaks? What the best way?